# SendGrid - Not Getting custom argument value

Tags: sendgrid

When sending the email throught Sendgrid,
I use the method AddCustomArg("custom_arg_name", "string_value") to add my custom arg. I'm using C#

When the sendgrid callback to my webhook, the response content sometimes has the value in 'custom_arg_name' field, sometimes it doesn't. Here is my response:

```
[{
"email": "email_String",
"timestamp": 1685204057,
"event": "bounce",
"reason": "unable to get mx info",
"smtp-id": "<string>",
"sg_event_id": "string",
"sg_message_id": "string",
"custom_arg_name": null, <-- here 
"CustomArgs": null 
}]
```

It's happend all event status: deferred, delivered, bounce

Comment: Can you please provide the full source code that you run when you try to send emails?